# Separate the values of a column based on specific words

Tags: python, dataframe, split

I have the following data frame:

```
country capital description
Greece  Athens  The COUNTRY of Greece has BEAUTIFUL islands
Italy   Rome    The COUNTRY of Rome has BEAUTIFUL roads
```

I want to split the value of the description column based on the capital words.

The data frame should end to have the following structure:

```
   country capital description
    Greece  Athens  The 
                    COUNTRY of Greece has 
                    BEAUTIFUL islands
    Italy   Rome    The 
                    COUNTRY of Rome has 
                    BEAUTIFUL roads
```

However, this is not possible as I get back

```
The length of values does not match the length of the index
```

so I thought to duplicate all rows except the values of the description column. Based on help here I come up with this

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(10)]
df['decription'] = df['description'].mask(df.index.duplicated(), '')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The above logic is not good as I am duplicating rows arbitrarily. The best way I think is to duplicate the rows based on the different capital words that appear on the description values. Note that the above data frame is a snippet of the whole data frame that expands on different rows. So it is not possible to know beforehand how many capital words appears on different rows. Maybe one, maybe more.

So how the come up with the desired outcome for the dataframe without getting the error above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Series.str.findall` and pass the `regex` to find all the substrings that end before the words in capital letter or the end of line character `$` using *lookahead assertion*, then `explode` it to have  multiple rows. On top of that, you can also set index if you wish to.

```py
df['description'] = df['description'].str.findall('([A-Z].*?)(?=\s[A-Z][A-Z]+|$)')
df.explode('description').set_index(['country', 'capital'])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
                           description
country capital                       
Greece  Athens                     The
        Athens   COUNTRY of Greece has
        Athens       BEAUTIFUL islands
Italy   Rome                       The
        Rome       COUNTRY of Rome has
        Rome           BEAUTIFUL roads
```

Comment: can the country also duplicate? Also how the regex can be changed in order to have this: The COUNTRY of Greece has, BEAUTIFUL islands. I think that living words like the has etc by their own does not look good. So maybe is better to have a word before the capital and a word after for example